# Using count with a union query

Tags: sql

This should be fairly straightforward but I can't find the exact syntax I need. I have a table which has a name1 and a name2 field. I just want a list of all the unique values in the fields and a count for each value. Eg:

```
name1       name2
-----------------
smith       jones
jones       williams
evans       williams
elliot      james
williams    smith
```

And I want:

```
name     count
--------------
smith    2
jones    2
Williams 3
evans    1
Elliot   1
james    1
```

To get the unique names I used a union query:

```
select name1 as myname
  from myTable
 union
select name2 as myname
  from myTable
```

But I can't find the right syntax for where the count goes. Can someone please put me out of my misery?

Answer (score 6):

You should use UNION ALL instead of UNION, because UNION will remove all duplicates while UNION ALL will not. And then you can use your union query as a subquery, and do the counts:

```
SELECT name, COUNT(*)
FROM
  (SELECT name1 name FROM tablename
   UNION ALL
   SELECT name2 name FROM tablename) s
GROUP BY
  name
```

Please see fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9798b/1).

Comment: Thanks for that. I tried amending my sql to be select name, count(*) as cnt
from ((select name1 as name from myTable) union all
      (select name2 as name from myTable))
     
group by name;   but it came back with a syntax error. What is the s in your code ? And I have used as name instead of just name. Is that correct?

Comment: An "s" is table alias, where table (or relation) is consisted with two `SELECT` statement combined with `UNION` operator. In fact, that two SELECT statements with UNION form a shape called DERIVED TABLE

Comment: Again thanks for the quick response - you guys are being very helpful. Except even including the s and other variations I'm still getting a "syntax error in join operation" message and it's highlighting the word union.

Comment: No worries - just had to get rid of the extra parentheses. Works great. Thanks all for your help.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `union all`:

```
select name, count(*) as cnt
from ((select name1 as name from t) union all
      (select name2 from t)
     ) t
group by name;
```

It is very important to use `union all` instead of `union`.  The latter removes duplicates, which you do not want.

For larger queries of this sort, it is more efficient to use `unpivot`, or the following construct:

```
select (case when n.n = 1 then name1 else name2 end) as name, count(*)
from t cross join
     (select 1 as n union all select 2) n
group by (case when n.n = 1 then name1 else name2 end)
```

The `union all` query will scan the table twice.  This version will generally only scan the table once.

Answer (score 1):

```
select t.name,count(t.name) count
from 
(
select name1 as name from tbl
union all 
select name2 as name from tbl
)t
group by t.name
```

**[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/12168/3)**

Answer (score 1):

Yet another typical way of solving such problems is to use ***with*** syntax:

```
-- Put here whatever entangled query you have and mark it "with"
with myQuery as 
  (select name1 as myName
     from myTable
    union all
    select name2 as myName
      from myTable)

-- And now do everything you want with myQuery, as if it's an ordinary table
  select myName as Name,
         Count(*)
    from myQuery
group by myName
```